# Projection of a ray onto a random polytope

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, random-matrices

Suppose $P$ is a polytope formed by $p$ (general) random planes in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We assume $p \asymp n$ and $P$ has a diameter $O(\sqrt{n})$. For any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, denote by $\operatorname{proj}_P (x)$ the projection of $x$ onto $P$.

Fix an $x$ with $\|x\| \ge \sqrt{n}$. My question is: does there exist a constant $C$ (independent of $x$) such that, with high probability as $n, p \rightarrow \infty$, $$\| \operatorname{proj}_P (c_1 x) - \operatorname{proj}_P (c_2 x) \| = 0.001\sqrt{n}$$ holds for all $c_1, c_2 > C$. We may assume $x$ is also random.